# Objective-c copying objects error

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to copy an array to another but it's not working. The original array I want to copy contains five objects; the resulting array is empty.

The array is set up as a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *drinks;
```

My `viewDidLoad` method looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    checkCounter = 0;
    Drink *drink1 = [[[Drink alloc] initWithImage:nil name:@"Test1" caffeine:11] autorelease];
    Drink *drink2 = [[[Drink alloc] initWithImage:nil name:@"Test2" caffeine:22] autorelease];
    Drink *drink3 = [[[Drink alloc] initWithImage:nil name:@"Test3" caffeine:33] autorelease];
    Drink *drink4 = [[[Drink alloc] initWithImage:nil name:@"Test4" caffeine:44] autorelease];
    Drink *drink5 = [[[Drink alloc] initWithImage:nil name:@"Test5" caffeine:55] autorelease];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: drink1, drink2, drink3, drink4, drink5, nil];
    drinks = [array mutableCopy];
}
```

[image: The first array fills up fine]
[image: The second array is empty]

Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work? I've tried using the regular `copy` method as well and simply assigning it but it doesn't work.

**EDIT 1**: The "array" variable actually gets initialised properly, however it does not get copied over. I have tried to directly initialise the "drinks" array but no matter what I try the "drinks" array remains empty.

**EDIT 2**: I have added screenshots to hopefully clear up some things.

Comment: Something must be wrong with the Drink objects and hence array might not be getting set properly. Just tried setting NSMutableArray *array to a few strings and did the mutable copy to another NSMutableArray. Everything works. Or have you forgotten to print the array in your NSLog if that's where you're checking? You just print TEST there.

Comment: You're retaining `array` twice; once with the init and once with the retain. You might want to change the retain to autorelease so it doesn't leak.

Comment: Do your Drink objects conform to the NSCopying protocol? That is, does your Drink object implement the method - (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone ?

Comment: In fact you seem rather confused about memory management in general, scattering `retain`s through your code like some sort of manic Johnny Appleseed. You might want to bother to read up on how memory management on iOS actually works and then revisit your code.

Comment: @trudycousin Whether or not the `Drink` class implements `NSCopying` is irrelevant;  the drinks are never copied in that code.

Comment: I hope my edit describes it a little better.

Answer (score 3):

First, you are leaking pretty much everything but the `drinks` array;  all of the individual drink objects and the `array` are over-retained once or twice in that code.

Secondly, `drinks` could only be empty if `drink1` through `drink5` are nil.  maybe `initWithImage:name:caffeine:` is returning `nil` when the image is `nil`?

Comment: The "array" actually contains everything, however when copying over the array to the new array it doesn't copy them over. I tried directly initialising the drinks array but it didn't fill it.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  You'll have to show more code and/or debugging logs and/or logging output.

Answer (score 0):

Drink object doesn't conform to the NSMutableCopying Protocol?
You should use this easier:

```
drinks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
```

require declare array as NSArray, or simpler:

```
drinks = [array copy];
```

if was me, your code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        checkCounter = 0;
        Drink *drink1 = [[[Drink alloc] initWithImage:nil name:@"Test1" caffeine:11] autorelease];
        Drink *drink2 = [[[Drink alloc] initWithImage:nil name:@"Test2" caffeine:22] autorelease];
        Drink *drink3 = [[[Drink alloc] initWithImage:nil name:@"Test3" caffeine:33] autorelease];
        Drink *drink4 = [[[Drink alloc] initWithImage:nil name:@"Test4" caffeine:44] autorelease];
        Drink *drink5 = [[[Drink alloc] initWithImage:nil name:@"Test5" caffeine:55] autorelease];
        drinks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: drink1, drink2, drink3, drink4, drink5, nil];
}
```

Comment: I need it to be an NSMutableArray. Also that code doesn't help either.